# How can I calculate the angle and proper turn direction between two 2D vectors?

Tags: 2d, vector

I am working on some movement AI where there are no obstacles and movement is restricted to the XY plane. I am calculating two vectors, **v**, the facing direction of ship 1, and **w**, the vector pointing from the position of ship 1 to ship 2.

I am then calculating the angle between these two vectors using the formula

```
arccos((v · w) / (|v| · |w|))
```

The problem I'm having is that `arccos` only returns values between 0° and 180°.  This makes it impossible to determine whether I should turn left or right to face the other ship.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you're using Unity, check out `Mathf.DeltaAngle()`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's much faster to use a 2d cross-product.  No costly trig function involved.

```
b2Vec2 target( ... );
b2Vec2 heading( ... );

float cross = b2Cross( target, heading );

if( cross == -0.0f )
   // turn around

if( cross == 0.0f )
  // already traveling the right direction

if( cross < 0.0f)
  // turn left

if( cross > 0.0f)
  // turn right
```

If you still need the actual angles I recommend using `atan2`.  `atan2` will give you the absolute angle of any vector.  To get the relative angle between any to vectors, calcuate their absolute angles and use simple subtraction.

```
b2Vec2 A(...);
b2Vec2 B(...);

float angle_A = std::atan2(A.y,A.x);
float angle_B = B.GetAngle(); // Box2D already figured this out for you.

float angle_from_A_to_B = angle_B-angle_A;
float angle_from_B_to_A = angle_A-angle_B;
```

Comment: After reading @Tetrad's answer I suppose you could combine a cross product and an `arccos`.  This way you'll only use one trig function, but still have the actual angle.  However I recommend against this optimization until you're sure you AI angle tracking is making a noticeable impact on your game's performance.

Comment: the magnitude of the cross product vector gives you the sin of the angle between them, not the cos.  So you need to use `arcsin`.

Comment: Yes, when converting between vectors and angles, atan2() is most definitely your friend.

Comment: Thanks! I've found that I actually don't really need the angle, grabbing the 2D cross product is simple enough for my needs.

Comment: If he's looking for the direction to steer, his `w` vector actually has all the information he needs.  He should go in the direction of the `w` vector.  The fact that it's "left" or "right" doesn't matter when you're working in vectors.

Comment: Also your `if( cross == -0.0f )` vs `if( cross == 0.0f )` check looks extremely fragile.

Comment: @bobobobo, with a physics engine it may not be an option to just pick a direction and move.  Magically turning can cause physic engines to freak out.  Further magically rotating looks terrible for animation as well.  So yes, you _can_ solve this without a notion of left or right, but a polished solution often needs these.

Comment: According to IEEE754 FP semantics, `0.0f == -0.0f`.  You can only distinguish +- 0.0 if you check the FP bit patterns, not using FP comparison operators.  i.e. the `already traveling the right direction` case can never be taken.

Answer (score 11):

Use arcsin of the 2D cross product (i.e the z component of the cross product vector).  That'll give you -90 to 90 which will let you know whether to go left or right.

Be careful because A cross B is not the same as B cross A.

Another strategy (but probably not as straight forward) is to calculate the "heading" of the two vectors using atan2 and then figuring out whether A pointing at X degrees needs to go left or right to go to B pointing at y degrees.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  To be clear for future browsers, taking the inverse sine of the magnitude of the 2d cross product would yield values between 0 and 90.  Taking the sine of the z-component of the 2d cross product yields the desired results.

Comment: @Error 454, you're absolutely right, fixed my post.

Answer (score 2):

Use *vectors* to redirect the ship.  This is how "steering behaviors" work -- you never need to calculate the angle, just use the vectors you have.  This is computationally much cheaper.

The vector `w` (vector from Ship 1 to Ship 2) is all the information you need.  Modify either ship 1's velocity vector or ship 1's acceleration vector (or even the heading vector directly) using a weighted version of `w`.

[image]

The *magnitude* of how far off ship 1 is off course (how badly v does not match up with w) can be found by using ( `1 - dot(v,w)` )

- (`dot(v,w)` is maximized when `v` and `w` line up exactly)
- (`1 - dot(v,w)`) gives 0 when `v` and `w` are completely lined up, provided `v` and `w` are normalized)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to find the absolute angle of a vector through normal geometry.

for example vector V = 2i - 3j;

absolute value of x coefficient = 2;

absolute value of y coefficient = 3;

angle = atan( 2 / 3 );  [ angle will be in between 0 to 90 ]

Based on quadrant angle will be changed.

if ( x coefficient < 0  and  y coefficient > 0 )
then angle = 180-angle;

if ( x coefficient < 0  and  y coefficient < 0 ) 
then angle = 180+angle;

if ( x coefficient > 0  and  y coefficient < 0 )
then angle = 360-angle;

if ( x coefficient > 0  and  y coefficient > 0 )
then angle = angle;

after finding angle of first and second vectors, just subtract first vector angle 
from second vector. Then you will get absolute angle between two vectors.

Comment: This is exactly what the atan2() function implements for you. :)

Comment: @NathanReed, yeah, but couldn't you use this method with a dot product to avoid the trig overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I should post a slightly different question and answer it myself; this is the closest question I could find to the one I had.

I'm doing 2D work in the html canvas, where I have rotation angles in radians rather than vectors. I needed the "turn angle" (ta) to get from "current heading" (h) to the "target heading" (t).

Here's my solution:

```
var ta = t - h,
    ata = Math.abs(ta)
;
if (ta > Math.PI) ta = (ta / ata) * (Math.PI - ata)
return ta;
```